# Read and parse perf.data

Tags: linux, perf

I am recording a performance counters frm linux using the command [`perf record`](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Sampling_with_perf_record).

I want to use the result `perf.data` as an input to other programming apps. Do you know how shall I read and parse the data in `perf.data`?

Comment: For those of us who haven't used the tool yet, could you post a sample from that datafile?

Comment: @slhck here is a sample snapshot of the file https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#Options_controlling_output_2

Answer (score 2):

There is builtin `perf.data` parser and printer in `perf` tool of linux tools with subcommand "script".

To convert `perf.data` file

```
perf script > perf.data.txt
```

To convert output of perf record in other file (`perf record -o filename.data`) use `-i` option:

```
perf script -i filename.data > filename.data.txt
```

`perf script` is documented at `man perf-script`, available online at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-script.1.html

> ```
>    perf-script - Read perf.data (created by perf record) and display
>    trace output
>
>    This command reads the input file and displays the trace recorded.
>
>        'perf script' to see a detailed trace of the workload that was
>        recorded.
> ```

Output of `perf script` are ASCII text readable by human. But they may be not easy to be parsed by scripts. `perf script -D` will show how individual events are stored in hex.